# How to allow one voter to vote for more than one candidate but disallow him from voting the same candidate again?

Tags: php, mysql

Dear friends i need a quick response i am creating a teachers rating system.students rate their teachers .i need one student to rate all the teachers but do not rate the teacher that has been rated once by that student.The problem in my codes is one student is rating only one teacher so what should i do?

```html
candidates.php

<?php
 if(isset($_SESSION['ALREADY'])){
 echo '<div style="background-color:#ffebe8; border:1px solid #dd3c10; padding:5px; color:#000; border-radius: 0px; font-family:tahoma; font-size:12px; margin-right:10px;">';
 echo $_SESSION['ALREADY']; 
 unset($_SESSION['ALREADY']);
 echo '</div>';
}?>
<?php
 if(isset($_SESSION['SAVED'])){
 echo '<div style="background-color:#abd46e; border:1px solid #518413; padding:5px; color:#000; border-radius: 0px; font-family:tahoma; font-size:12px;margin-right:10px;">';
 echo $_SESSION['SAVED']; 
 unset($_SESSION['SAVED']);
 echo '</div>';
}?>
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("couldnt connnect to server");
mysql_select_db("project")  or die ("couldnt connnect to database");
$find_data=mysql_query("select * from teacher");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($find_data))
{
$id=$row['tid'];
$name=$row['tname'];
$sub=$row['subject'];
$current_rating=$row['rating'];
$hits=$row['hits'];
echo"
<form action='submit-votes.php' method='post'>
$name:<select name='rating'>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
<option>6</option>
<option>7</option>
<option>8</option>
<option>9</option>
<option>10</option>

</select>
<input type='hidden' value='$sub' name='subject'>
<input type='submit' value='Rate'>Current Rating"; echo round($current_rating,2); echo"
</form>
";


}?>



submit-votes.php

<?php
 //session
 session_start();

 //databse connection
 include_once 'config.php';

 //Connect to mysql server
 $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
 if(!$link) {
  die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
 }
 
 //Select database
 $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
 if(!$db) {
  die("Unable to select database");
 }
 
  //Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
 function clean($str) {
  $str = @trim($str);
  if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
   $str = stripslashes($str);
  }
  return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
 }
 
  if($_SESSION['SESS_VOTERS'] != ''){
  $qry = "SELECT * FROM votes WHERE voters='$_SESSION[SESS_VOTERS]'";
  $result = mysql_query($qry);
  if($result) {
   if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $errmsg_arr = '<i>You already submitted your votes. Please <a href="logout.php" style="color:#004e49;"><u>Logout.</u></a></i>';
    $_SESSION['ALREADY'] = $errmsg_arr;
    $errflag = true;
    session_write_close();
    header('location: candidates.php');
  exit();
   }
   @mysql_free_result($result);
  }
  else {
   die("Query failed");
  }
 }


 //student votes
 $sql=("INSERT INTO votes (voters) VALUES ('$_SESSION[SESS_VOTERS]')");
 
$sub=$_POST['subject'];
$post_rating=$_POST['rating'];
$find_data=mysql_query("select * from teacher where subject='$sub'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($find_data))
{
$id=$row['tid'];
$current_rating=$row['rating'];
$current_hits=$row['hits'];
}
$new_hits=$current_hits +1;
$update_hits=mysql_query("update teacher set hits='$new_hits' where tid='$id'");

$pre_rating=$current_rating+$post_rating;
$new_rating=$pre_rating/2;

$update_rating=mysql_query("update teacher set rating='$new_rating' where tid='$id'");
 if (!mysql_query($sql,$link))
   {
   die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
   }
   //show a message query excecuted.
 $saved ='<i>You have successfully submitted your votes. Thank you for voting.</i>';
 $_SESSION['SAVED'] = $saved;
 session_write_close();
 header("location: candidates.php");
 mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Store the user's ID in the votes table and add a unique constraint on the user ID AND the teacher's ID (i.e. one single constraint for multiple columns).

Comment: Dear Mike i have stored the student id in votes table but after that the student is unable to rate another teacher and if i also store the rated teacher id then another student could not rate that teacher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A student can rate a particular teacher only once.

```
create schema testSunday01; -- create a new DB so as not to mess up yours
use testSunday01;   -- use it (make it the active one)

create table teacher
(   teacherId int auto_increment primary key,
    name varchar(200) not null
);

create table student
(   studentId int auto_increment primary key,
    name varchar(200) not null
);

create table vote
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    studentId int not null,
    teacherId int not null,
    rating int not null,
    unique key(studentId,teacherId), -- enforces a non dupe

    -- enforce Referential Integrity with FK constraints
    foreign key (studentId) references student(studentId),
    foreign key (teacherId) references teacher(teacherId)

    -- to student and teacher tables here
);

drop schema testSunday01; -- easy cleanup, bye bye test database
```

If the concept of `term` factors into it, like Spring2016, then that would be another column and could be part of the unique composite key (index) too.

Mysql manual pages on [Foreign Keys](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) and [PRIMARY KEY and UNIQUE Index Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/constraint-primary-key.html).

Comment: please guide me how to use foreign key constraints as i have not done it before

Comment: best I can do. I am off helping other people.

Comment: okkkkk thank you so much .i appreciate your work . i m going to try it

Answer (score 1):

The part to change is:

```
    $qry = "SELECT * FROM votes WHERE voters='$_SESSION[SESS_VOTERS]'";
```

Your code verifies only the student ID. You must change your request to verify the teacher ID as well, by using AND.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp - Please don't uncheck the green mark if I give the correct answer just because another user asked you to.